# Problema con ngModel

Tags: json, angular, typescript

tengo un problema con ngModel en los input de mi formulario y no sé como resolverlo.

Tengo una API con php que me devuelve valores en este formato.

```
[
  {
    "idPotencial": 1,
    "Nombre": "ssssss",
    "Apellidos": "ssssss",
    "Fecha": "2021-06-22 00:00:00",        
    "Observaciones": "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"
}]
```

En angular tengo un servicio que llama a la api y lo castea a una interface como modelo.

```
export interface IPotenciales{
       idPotencial: any
       Nombre: string
       Apellidos: String
       Fecha: Date
       Observaciones: string
 }
```

y la llamada la hago tal que así

```
 getPotencialesById(idPotencial : any) : Observable<IPotenciales>  {
 
      return this.http.get<IPotenciales>(url)

 }
```

Pues bien, el problema que tengo es que al usar ngModel en el formulario no me muestra nada. En el HTML he colocado esto para ver si me trae los datos.

```
  {{ this.contactoPotencial }}
```

y

```
  {{ this.contactoPotencial | json }}
```

En la primera salida me saca el siguiente resultado

```
 [object Object]
```

y en la segunda así

```
 [ { "idPotencial": 1, "Nombre": "Gemma", "Apellidos": "Tendero Ozores", "Fecha": "2021-06-22 00:00:00", "Observaciones": "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" } ]
```

Pongo el código del componente para ver como lo cargo.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IPotenciales } from 'src/app/models/IPotenciales';
import { PotencialesService } from 'src/app/servicios/potenciales.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-contact',
  templateUrl: './edit-contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-contact.component.scss']
})

export class EditContactComponent implements OnInit {
    contactoPotencial : IPotenciales = { } as IPotenciales
    idPotencial : any

    constructor( private fb: FormBuilder,
        private servicio : PotencialesService,
        private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
     this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( ({ id })=>{
         this.idPotencial = id
     })

     this.getPotencial()
 }

 getPotencial(){

     this.servicio.getPotencialesById(this.idPotencial).subscribe( data =>{
        this.contactoPotencial = data 
     })

}}
```

EDITO:

Se me olvido poner el codigo del formulario

```
{{ this.contactoPotencial | json }}

<form class="form-horizontal floating-labels" role="form" #myForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-body">
      <h3 class="box-title">Datos del contacto</h3>
      <hr class="m-t-0 m-b-40">
      <div class="row my-2">
          <div class="col-md">
              <div class="form-floating m-b-40">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Fecha"
                    placeholder="Seleccione una fecha">
                <label for="Fecha">Fecha</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Origen" name="Origen" placeholder="Origen">
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label for="Origen">Origen</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row my-2">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" id="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre"
                    class="form-control" name="Nombre"
                    [(ngModel)]="this.contactoPotencial.Nombre">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-floating">
                      <input type="text" id="Apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos"
                          class="form-control" name="Apellidos"
                          [(ngModel)]="this.contactoPotencial.Apellidos">
                          <span class="bar"></span>
                          <label for="Apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
      </div>

      <!--/row-->
      <div class="row my-2">
          <div class="col-md">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-floating">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                            name="ObjetivoConsulta"
                            id="ObjetivoConsulta" placeholder="Objetivo">
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <label for="ObjetivoConsilta">¿Cual es tu objetivo de consulta?</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row my-2">

          <div class="col-md">

              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-floating">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Intentos Anteriores"
                          name="IntentosAnteriores"
                          id="IntentosAnteriores">
                      <span class="bar"></span>
                      <label for="IntentosAnteriores">¿Intentos anteriores?</label>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                  <option selected>Selecciona uno</option>
                  <option value="1">Si</option>
                  <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <label for="IntentosAnteriores">¿Lo ha conseguido?</label>
              </div>
          </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
              <div class="form-froup">
                  <div class="form-floating">

                      <input type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          id="QueNoFunciono"
                          name="QueNoFunciono"
                          placeholder="¿Que no ha funcionado?">
                      <span class="bar"></span>
                      <label for="QueNoFunciono">¿Que no ha funcioando? 
                      </label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!--/row-->
      <h3 class="box-title">Observaciones</h3>
      <hr class="m-t-0 m-b-40">
      <div class="row my-2">
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-floating">
              <textarea class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Observaciones"
                   id="Observaciones"
                   name="Observaciones" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
              <label for="Observaciones">Observaciones</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> <i 
                     class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Grabar</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn- 
                inverse">Cancelar</button>
                  </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

Por algún motivo no me esta parseando de forma correcta el JSON de la api a mi modelo en Angular (o eso creo). Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto.

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: falta lo más importante: el código del formulario

Comment: @OscarMañasGarcia Prueba a que cuando le pases el objeto desde PHP, no este en un array

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias Pablo, lo acabo de editar. Y esta puesto.

Comment: Gracias @Srsole, es lo único que me falta por probar. Estoy usando Slim 3 para el REST API y no sé cómo formatear la salida aún... Uso el metodo ->withJson() para la salida pero tengo que ver como quitarle los [] de inicio y fin.

Comment: @OscarMañasGarcia prueba en local indicando [0] cuando lo uses el JSON, comenta

Comment: Gracias @Srsole me has solucionado la vida! jeje. En la respuesta del json le he puesto [0] que sería el primer elemento y funciona a la perfeccion. Tendré que revisar la api pues... Gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la llamada de la `api`, esta dentro de un array.

Al llamar a tu `JSON` pon `[0]` detras para indicar el numero del elemento del array, y detras de este un punto `.` y la propiedad que deseas acceder.